# where is the object/array storing the browser timers

Tags: javascript, browser

judging from this quote `timeoutID is the numerical ID of the timeout, which can be used later with window.clearTimeout()`. from MDN there must be some object or array which holds the intervals and/or timeouts stored? I am having a hard time finding this info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no publicly accessible data structure that automatically holds all active timer ids.  That is simply not part of the standard definition of Javascript in the browser environment.

That may exist somewhere inside of the JS engine, but it is not made accessible to normal Javascript.

If you want to be able to stop a timer, then you must save your own timerID so you can then use `clearTimeout()` or `clearInterval()` with it.

```
var timerId = setTimeout(function() {
    // code here
}, 1000);
```

Then, somewhere else in your code at some future point in time, you can decide to cancel that timer.

```
if (some condition) {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
}
```

---

### Named Timers

FYI, you could make your own "named" timers that would keep track of all the timer ids for you.  In this example, when you create a timer, you just give it a unique name and you can then clear it later by that name.  It's up to you to give each separate timer a unique name.  This could easily be extended to support intervals too.

```
// declaration
function TimerHolder() {
    // in ES6, you could use a Map object here
    var names = {};

    this.setTimer = function(fn, t, name) {
        // clear any prior timer with the same name
        this.clearTimer(name);

        // add leading underscore so we don't conflict with object properties
        var moniker = "_" + name;
        var id = setTimeout(function() {
            delete names[moniker];
            fn();
        }, t);
        names[moniker] = id;
    }

    this.clearTimer = function(name) {
        var moniker = "_" + name;
        var id = names[moniker];
        if (id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
            delete names[moniker];
        }
    }

    this.getActiveTimers = function() {
        return Object.keys(names).map(function(name) {
            // remove leading underscore from keys
            return name.slice(1);
        });
    }
}

var timers = new TimerHolder();

// usage
timers.setTimer(myFunc, 1000, "mouseTimeout");

// some time later
if (some condition) {
    timers.clearTimer("mouseTimeout");
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and the timerHolder constructor, very straight forward and easy to comprehend

Answer (score 2):

Not by default. `setTimeout` returns an ID which you can use to cancel the timeout.

```
var id = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("I'll never be called");
}, 500);
clearTimeout(id);
```

You could store the IDs in an object or array if you wanted to keep a collection of them but you would have to manually control that.